# POSTing arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist, http-post

in most of the q&a its Name Value Pair that is used to POST;

> `List<NameValuePair> myBooks = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();`

```
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(myBooks));
```

but when I try to change the params to to arrayList,

> `List<Books> myBooks`= //fulfilled from another class"

I get this:

> `The constructor UrlEncodedFormEntity(List<myBooks>) is undefined`

is it really impossible to post List instead of ValuePair without Jackson lib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [the API](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/entity/UrlEncodedFormEntity.html) you can see that the list must must extend `NameValuePair`.
So your own class would need to extend the `NameValuePair` class as well.

But why would this be? If you look at the third line of the code you provided

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(myBooks));
```

The important part here is noticing the `UrlEncodedFormEntity`.
 The UrlEncoded data would consist of simple name & value pairs, like this:

```
name=bob&age=20
```

If you provide a list that already consists of names with their values(`NameValuePair`), you get this done for you, by the library.

If you want to just POST arbitary data, you can do this by yourself, by using [StringEntity](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/StringEntity.html).

```
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(myString));
```

In any case, please do not forget to add the revelant content-type header to your POST!

Comment: dear Zavior; I need to Post lots of name=bob&age=20; what do you recommend ?

Comment: Without knowing anything about the system & context, it is pretty hard to say anything. You mentioned jackson, are you trying to post from data, or perhaps, json? Is the receiving end something you can change? In any case, it is out of the scope of this question I think.

Comment: Im using Json, but quick quick; is it really bad idea to loop for each listArray,cast to NameValue?

Comment: Unless they really are NameValuePair objetcs, yeah.

Comment: obj Book; "String author, int year,String pub, String desc"

Comment: am I ok then?! please say yes, Im "" this close to lose my sight.

Comment: Well, that object looks like you could make 3 different name & value pairs out of it, so nope..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57630/discussion-between-shervin-and-zavior).